# Mediawiki: entering code into skin to only appear on certain pages?

Tags: mediawiki, facebook-comments, skin

**Background**

I am trying to add a Facebook Comment box into my Mediaskin php file, but when I use the code below the box appears on every page.

**Code**

```
<!-- /debughtml -->
</div>
<br />
<center><div class="fb-comments" data-width="800" data-num-posts="100" data-colorscheme="dark"></div></center>
<!-- /bodyContent -->
```

**Question**

How can I make the facebook comments appear only on read pages (pages with `index.php?title=` in the URL, but without `&action=edit` at the end of the URL?

Comment: why not check the $_GET array, if the action key is not set in the array, you can hide it..

Comment: i have researched into $_GET and made some new code, which is throwing up a synthax error further down the page code. the new code is over 500 characters, too long to post here, you can see the code i made here [link]http://www.htmlforums.com/html-xhtml/t-making-code-only-run-on-certain-urls-152543.html#post830611[/link] do this code look correct?